# Calculating $(-8)^{2/3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$(-8)^{2/3}$

I see this as $(-8^{1/3})^2$ = $-2^2$ =  4

Or $(-8^2)^{1/3} = 64^{1/3} = 4$

However, Google, Sagemath and some web calculators are saying this is equal to $-4$.

And when written as $(-8)^{2/3}$, I either get an error or $$-2 + 3.46410162 i$$
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Notice that $8^{2/3}=(8^{1/3})^2=2^2=4$, then
$$-8^{2/3}=-4$$
Which is different than $(-8)^{2/3}$

Comment: Look at edit $(-8)^{2/3)$ doesn't make too much sense either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$-(8)^{2/3} = -\sqrt[3]{8^2} = -\sqrt[3]{64} = -4$$

Since

$$4\cdot 4\cdot 4 = 64$$

**If instead the minus is inside the brakets**

$$(-8)^{2/3} = 4\cdot \sqrt[3]{-1}$$

Then you can see

$$-1 = e^{i\pi}$$

And so on..

Answer (score 4):

You were wrong when you said "I see this as..."

We, and by we I mean me and the calculators, see this as
$$-8^{2/3} = -(8^{2/3}) = -(2^2) = -(4) = -4$$

Parentheses count my friend. Be careful!

---

Post edit:
If you are trying to calculate $(-8)^{2/3}$, all I have to say is
welcome to the world of [complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number)! :)

Answer (score 2):

**Note that the question was edited as this post was being made.** The original question was $-8^{2/3}$.

When people write $-a^b$, they mean the negative to be outside of the exponent, so $-a^b = -(a^b)$. This is different from $(-a)^b$.

Hence,
$-8^{2/3} = -(8^{2/3}) = -4$.

Another way to remember this is via the order of operations: PEMDAS. $-$ is the same as multiplying by $-1$. Exponents come first. So do $8^{2/3}$ before applying the negative.

Comment: Fair! But even with parentheses it isn't 4

Comment: @EricJohnson Have you tried doing `8^(2/3)`?

Comment: @EricJohnson For example, [Google](https://www.google.com/#q=8%5E(2%2F3)).

Comment: https://www.google.ca/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=lpbxVpb4JKzd8geNsaOgCQ#q=(-8)%5E(2%2F3)

Comment: @EricJohnson That is completely different. Note that in my post, I said $-a^b = -(a^b)$. So $-8^{2/3} = -(8^{2/3})$. On [Google](https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=lpbxVpb4JKzd8geNsaOgCQ#q=-(8%5E(2%2F3))).

Comment: That is the second part of the question

Answer (score 0):

$$-8^{2/3}=-\left(\sqrt[3]{8}\right)^2=-2^2=-4$$